# How can i grab the ID of all posts?

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

Recently got into the XML-RPC Library in python and i need to grab the ID of all posts in my wordpress website. I tried using the `EditPost()` command but it seems that the ID of the posts are needed.

In the following code i am trying to change all posts to draft

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts
from wordpress_xmlrpc import WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import EditPost

wp = Client('website-link', 'x', 'x')

post = WordPressPost()
#Posts returns the name of the posts not IDs
posts = wp.call(posts.GetPosts())
print(posts)


for post in posts:
    post.post_status = 'draft'
    wp.call(EditPost(post,post))
print('done')
```

Comment: I don't know XML-RPC, but the [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPosts) says it returns [`string post_id`](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/wordpress.html#wordpresspost), the `WordPressPost` object has an `id` attribute. Printing the post won't show it, which is maybe why you thought it wasn't there? This code worked for me:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts
wp = Client("https://wordpress.example.com/xmlrpc.php", "admin", "password")
allposts = wp.call(GetPosts())
for thepost in allposts:
    print thepost.id
```

So your code should work by changing your loop as follows:

```
for post in posts:
    post.post_status = 'draft'
    wp.call(EditPost(post.id, post))
```

Comment: That did it miken32, big thanks for the clarification!

Comment: It may be worth mentioning for future visitors that, according to [the documentation](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/posts.html#advanced-querying), `GetPosts` only returns the ten most recent posts.